# Finding the Directional Derivative at the origin?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the directional derivative of $f (x, y) = ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ at
$(x, y) ≠ (0, 0)$ toward the origin.

What I am confused about this problem is what are the points in this problem and what is the vectors? I think its $(0,0)$ and $<0,0>$. But I am unsure. I know the partial derivative is

$\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ = $\frac{1}{x+y}$

$\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ = $\frac{1}{x+y}$

$u = 0$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put in the square root sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points in this problem are $(x,y)$, for any point other than $(0,0)$. Your partial derivatives are wrong. We have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac 12\ln(x^2+y^2) \\
 &= \frac 12\frac1{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2) \\
 &= \frac 12\frac1{x^2+y^2}2x \\
 &= \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}$$

You should be able to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$ in almost the same way.

The vector is $\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\rangle$.

The phrase "toward the origin" means that the derivative vector is parallel to the vector from the origin to the point $\langle x,y\rangle$. If you find the angle you will see this is the case. You can also see it is the case if you realize that, in polar coordinates,

$$f(x,y)=\ln r$$

so that the angle $\theta$ is not involved at all. The derivative therefore also only depends on $\vec r$, the vector from the origin. You should be able to express the derivative vector as an easy formula of $\vec r$.

Comment: Then the directional derivative is $- \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ because it is the opposite direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked to compute the directional derivative along a vector that points *from* an unspecified point $(x,y)$ *toward* the origin.  The reason why the problem specifies that $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ is because if $(x,y)$ were at the origin then "the vector that points from $(x,y)$ towards the origin" wouldn't make any sense.